# SQL Server Agent Doesn't Allow Me To Run Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

There are a number of SQL Server Agent jobs set up that run on schedules and they run OK. When I use Management Studio, right click any job and select "Start at Step...", a dialog pops up and says "starting..." then success, but the "executing..." part of the dialog never "comes back" - the job seems to run forever. If you "View Job History", it looks like I never launched the job.

I created a new job with 1 step (select 1) as a test. This job never returns, either. I scheduled the job to run every 10 seconds. It never runs, according to "View Job History".

I have all roles (including dbcreator, public, serveradmin and sysadmin) on a SQL Server 2005 install.

Answer (score 0):

which sp do you have applied?  i remember there being an issue with sp1 or 2 on running jobs, especially if ssms is not the same version as the server.

Comment: sp2 enterprise, with ssms 2008

Comment: if you could i'd recommend going to sp3.  i'm fairly certain the issue i had was with sp2 and sp3 fixed it.

Comment: I think that you are probably right. I can't control that db, but we are switching over to 2008, anyway.